# How to select rows where date is in index in Python Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have DataFrame in Pythonlike below where data is in index (we can name this column "date"):

[image]

and I would like to select all column of this DF where data in index is > than 01.01.2020, how can I do it? (be aware that date is in index).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, dayfirst=True)
df1 = df[df.index > '2020-01-01']
```

Or:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, dayfirst=True)
df1 = df[df.index > pd.to_datetime('2020-01-01')]
```

Comment: I have error like below when I sue your code: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'Timestamp'